# In which is thread ContentProvider is running?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

I have confused about in witch thread `ContentResolver` is running?

I have my app and I implemented `ContentResolver` for get other application acceess to file from my application private folder.

I override `openFile` method. Is I am right that this method starts from my app main thread?

Answer (score 0):

All ContentProviders need run in their own thread because the `ContentProviders` can be used by other application as well to read/write resources. Just like the **Contacts**.

Comment: Do you mean main thread of application where `ContentProvider` initiated by 'own thread'? Or do you just mean any thread created with this application user permissions?

Comment: just call Log.d(TAG, "thread " + Thread.currentThread) in your openFile method and you will see the thread where your method is called

Answer (score 0):

The `openFile()` method is not called on the main thread. It is called on some worker thread. This must be thread-safe because it can be called on multiple threads simultaneously.